# objective-c I want to know the syntax for passing arrays of pointer to a class method

Tags: objective-c

I want to know the syntax for passing arrays of pointer to a class method.

```
Myclass *arr[TOTAL];
```

what is the syntax for the class method to take arr?

Comment: Telling people that you hate the thing they presumably like if they can answer your question probably won't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number of elements in the array is fixed, then

```
+ (void)someMethod:(MyClass *[])array;
```

is sufficient. Otherwise, pass the number of elements in the array:

```
+ (void)someMethod:(MyClass *[])array count:(NSUInteger)count;
```

In order to use the methods above,

```
MyClass *array[TOTAL];
array[0] = …;
array[1] = …;
…
array[TOTAL - 1] = …;

[MyClass someMethod:array];
```

or

```
[MyClass someMethod:array count:TOTAL];
```

Answer (score 3):

It is extremely atypical to pass a language array full of Objective-C objects or classes to a method.

I'd suggest:

```
+ (void) classMethod: (NSArray  *) arrayOfClasses;
```

And:

```
[MyClass classMethod: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [Foo class], [Bar class], nil]];
```

Answer (score 1):

A class method starts with a `+`.  Making it take an array as a parameter is done the same way as you would do it with any other pointer-taking method/function in C or Objective-C:

```
+ (void)myClassMethod:(MyClass **)arrayOfMyClassPointers;
```

It is a little strange to be using a C-style array to hold pointers to objects, though - what are you really trying to do?